# How to solve moderncv troubles?

Tags: moderncv

I´m trying to create a PDF with moderncv...however I dont know what is the issue here...spent already hours with trouble shooting without success. could someone hlep please?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}               
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             

\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize }



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\maketitle



\vspace{-2mm}

\subsection{Nicht akademische Beschäftigung}


\cventry{2009--2014}{Consultant}{IP-basierte Dienstleistungen-Ranstad}{}{Schweiz}{Winterthur.}


\cventry{11/2006--06/2007}{Consultant}{Linguistische Dienstleistungen: Carl-Duisburg Stiftung}{}{}{Russland}{Moskau.}


\cventry{02/2006--05/2006}{Praktikum}{Erstellung von Good Governance Indices - Büro des Premierminister}{}{Kampala}{Uganda.}


\subsection{Akademische Beschäftigung}


\cventry{02/2006--05/2006}{Praktikum: Erstellung von Good Governance Indices}{Büro des Premierminister}{Russland}{Moskau.}


\cventry{2008--2010}{Wissenschaftliche Hilfskraft: Osteuropäische Geschichte}{}{}{Universität Konstanz.}
%Section

\section{Ausbildung}

\cventry{Seit 10/2013}{Master of Science} { Data Analysis}{}{{Universität Konstanz.}

\cventry{10/2008--03/2012}{Master of Arts}{Osteuropastudien und Politikwissenschaft}{Universität Konstanz,Universität Tartu.}{}\cventry{10/2004--09/2008}{Bachelor of Arts}{Soziologie & Politikwissenschaft}{}{Universität Konstanz, RGGU.}

\cventry{2000--2003}{Abitur}{Technisches Gymnasium}{}{Rastatt.}

\vspace{-3mm}
%Section

\section{Sprachkenntnisse}

\vspace{3mm}

\cvlanguage{Russisch}{Muttersprache}

\cvlanguage{Deutsch}{Muttersprache}

\cvlanguage{English}{Verhandlungssicher}
%Section

\section{Interessen}


\cvline{Interessen}{\small Statistik, Russische Literatur}
\vspace{-3mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Can you shorten your example to a minimal example that shows your problem?

Comment: The process end with the \cventry...and the latex suggestions dont make sence

Comment: I think thats the part with issues

Comment: If there is an answer provided, there is no need to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted all not needed packages and corrected several errors in your code.

For example: without `\name{John}{Doe}` the command `\maketitle` can't work.

Have a look on this compiling MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}   % without this \maketitle throws error!


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\subsection{Nicht akademische Beschäftigung}
%\cventry{1 Datum}{2 Art}{3 Beschreibung}{4 Beschreibung2}{5 Land}{6 Stadt.}
 \cventry{2009--2014}{Consultant}{IP-basierte Dienstleistungen-Ranstad}{4}{Schweiz}{Winterthur.}
 \cventry{11/2006--06/2007}{Consultant}{Linguistische Dienstleistungen: Carl-Duisburg Stiftung}{4}{Russland}{Moskau.}
 \cventry{02/2006--05/2006}{Praktikum}{Erstellung von Good Governance Indices~-- Büro des Premierminister}{4}{Kampala}{Uganda.}

\subsection{Akademische Beschäftigung}
 \cventry{02/2006--05/2006}{Praktikum: Erstellung von Good Governance Indices}{Büro des Premierminister}{4}{Russland}{Moskau.}
 \cventry{2008--2010}{Wissenschaftliche Hilfskraft: Osteuropäische Geschichte}{3}{4}{5}{Universität Konstanz.}

\section{Ausbildung}
 \cventry{Seit 10/2013}{Master of Science}{Data Analysis}{4}{Universität Konstanz.}{6}
 \cventry{10/2008--03/2012}{Master of Arts}{Osteuropastudien und Politikwissenschaft}{Universität Konstanz,Universität Tartu.}{5}{6}
 \cventry{10/2004--09/2008}{Bachelor of Arts}{Soziologie \& Politikwissenschaft}{4}{Universität Konstanz, RGGU.}{6}
 \cventry{2000--2003}{Abitur}{Technisches Gymnasium}{4}{Rastatt.}{6}

\section{Sprachkenntnisse}
 \cvlanguage{Russisch}{Muttersprache}{3}
 \cvlanguage{Deutsch}{Muttersprache}{3}
 \cvlanguage{English}{Verhandlungssicher}{3}

\section{Interessen}
\cvline{Interessen}{\small Statistik, Russische Literatur}
\end{document}
```

You had a lot of missing brackets `{}` inside your `\cventry` commands. I corrected it. You need to write six pairs like this:

```
\cventry{1 Datum}{2 Art}{3 Beschreibung}{4 Beschreibung2}{5 Land}{6 Stadt.}
```